# How do I make an http request with fetch in node? node-fetch

Tags: node.js, fetch

I am trying to make a request in node.  Here is my code:

```
fetch("http://www.test.com", options).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);

    return err;
  });
```

Here is the error that I get.
`TypeError: Only HTTP(S) protocols are supported`

I have tried to create a new agent and pass it in the options like this:

```
const httpAgent = new http.Agent({
    keepAlive: true
});
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
    keepAlive: true
});

const options = {
    agent: function (_parsedURL) {
        if (_parsedURL.protocol == 'http:') {
            return httpAgent;
        } else {
            return httpsAgent;
        }
    }
}
```

I still get the same error.

When I run this in the client, I can send an `http` or an `https` request to the same `fetch` and there isn't an issue.  Apparently it is different on with node.

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: This looks very weird. Are you sure it is saved? Has webpack recompiled? Does node need to restart? Are you sure the error is for that line? I've used `node-fetch` a ton myself, and this should work.

Comment: i don't know, they force it to be https https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/master/src/request.js?ts=2#L197

Answer (score 7):

Check if you've passed a url with a protocol. Error "Only HTTP(S) protocols are supported" means that there's neither HTTP nor HTTPS protocol found.

Comment: Spot on! I was passing through "localhost:3001", when I added the http:// at the beginning I didn't get this error anymore.